# Clean up bad JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to use a web service that returns JSON data that JavaScript cannot parse directly. I use a jQuery AJAX call and get the error message "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : " in the Chrome developer console. How can I fix this? Here's a sample of what I get from the service:

```
{
"DepartureBoard":{
    "noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"http://api.vasttrafik.se/v1/hafasRestDepartureBoard.xsd",
    "error":"No journeys found",
    "errorText":"There was no journey found for the requested board or time.",
    "$":""
}
}
```

Here is my code. The error function below is executed.

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: myurl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'onSuccess',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        this.onSuccess( data );
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // prints debug messages now
    }
});
```

**Update**: I'm doing a request to a remote resource. This seems to complicate things.

**Update 2**: Maybe I've been going at this the wrong way. I thought it would be trivial to parse JSON data, but it's seemingly in the wrong format as some have pointed out.

**Update 3**: I found a workaround. By creating a minimal PHP file with the function call `file_get_contents($url)` I can do an AJAX call to my own server. With JSONP and some modifications inspired by the answers below, I got it working. (By accident, wrapping everything in minimal .php files instead of .html actually solved another problem; my JavaScript files were being cached.)

Comment: are you sure it's the json that's the issue? according to http://jsonlint.com/, that's valid json...

Comment: It's valid JSON, how are you parsing it?

Comment: You will also want to provide us with what's happening to the json data in `onSuccess()`.

Comment: The response you listed seems to be lacking the "*padding*" of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). The JSON string should be wrapped in a function call so the response can be parsed as JavaScript. The error is because JavaScript treats a leading `{` means a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) rather than an `Object`.

Comment: Odd. The jQuery API says the error handler should NEVER be called for jsonp: "Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests." http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: It typically does get called anyway. Not sure why.

Comment: For JSONP requests to a remote resource, the following parameters that you are using are ignored: `crossDomain, contentType`. Additionally, cache is defaulted to false for jsonp and script requests, so it is also not needed. Your request is failing because the service either doesn't support JSONP or you are using the service incorrectly. refer to the documentation for said service.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think the service has to absolutely support jsonp, jQuery should wrap the returned data in a function to execute which is why the jsonPCallback property can be set to define your own name for the wrapping function. Otherwise it generates a function name for you.

Comment: @jlafay Sadly, the onSuccess function is not executed.

Comment: @jlafay that is incorrect. if the service doesn't wrap the request in a function, the data can't be retrieved using jsonp, because at that point the data being returned is json, not jsonp.

Comment: Yes I just realized that isn't being called anyways, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to make a request to a remote resource, that wasn't clear in the question.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I can't change the format of the response. How can I make JavaScript accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm acctually using the same service, this is how

```
            var tripQuestion = "https://api.vasttrafik.se/bin/rest.exe/v1/trip?authKey=" + authKey + "&format=json&jsonpCallback=searchForTripJSON" + "&numTrips=6";
            if (time && date) tripQuestion = tripQuestion + "&date=" + date + "&time=" + time;
            if (departure.id) tripQuestion = tripQuestion + "&originId=" + departure.id
            if (destination.id) tripQuestion = tripQuestion + "&destId=" + destination.id
            else tripQuestion = tripQuestion + "&destCoordLat=" + destination.lat+ "&destCoordLong=" + destination.lon+ "&destCoordName=" + destination.name
            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: 'GET',
                async: true,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: tripQuestion,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonpCallback: 'searchForTripJSON',
                jsonp: false,
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    //put success code here
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    //put error code here
                },
                complete: function (data) {
                    //put complete code here
                }
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but I found another soultion by wrapping code in PHP.

Comment: I guess you just download it to your server first.Did you ever try my solution?

Comment: I did just now. It worked, but I needed to end the AJAX function call `});` and comment out the variables.

Answer (score 2):

You are requesting JSONP, but that's not what is being returned.  JSONP is *not* JSON.  JSONP is actually just a JavaScript file.  You want the response to be:

```
onSuccess({
    "DepartureBoard":{
        "noNamespaceSchemaLocation":"http://api.vasttrafik.se/v1/hafasRestDepartureBoard.xsd",
        "error":"No journeys found",
        "errorText":"There was no journey found for the requested board or time.",
        "$":""
    }
});
```

Note how the object is wrapped in a function call.

Also, some of the parameters in your `$.ajax` call are incorrect.

The `contentType` sets the `Content-type` header of the ***request***, it's  the content type of the ***request body***.  It has nothing to do with the *response*.  Get rid of it.

The `jsonpCallback` is only needed if the server doesn't accept a `callback` parameter as a GET parameter.  It's only for if the server uses a hard-coded string as the callback name.

Without it, jQuery will append `callback=someFunctionName` to your URL and expects that the JSONP response will use that as the callback name.

For example, the JSONP response should be (using PHP as an example here):

```
echo $_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).');';
```

Finally, `this.onSuccess( data );` inside your `success` probably doesn't do what you think it does.  I suggest removing that line.  Inside your `success` function `data` will be the object returned from the call.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over what the remote resource returns.

Comment: @David: JSONP needs to be enabled on the remote server.  The response needs to be in the form of: `onSuccess({})`. If it's not wrapped in a function call, it won't work.  If the remote server doesn't return a JSONP response, then you're gonna need to find another solution.  One solution is to use your server as a proxy to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to parse it. It's already an object. How are you outputting json on server side? Try this client side:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(myurl + '?callback=?', 'param=value',  function(result) {
        console.log(result.DepartureBoard.errorText);
    });
  });
```

should console out: "There was no journey found for the requested board or time."
P.S. if it's PHP on the backend then you should:

```
$error = array(
"DepartureBoard" => array(
       "noNamespaceSchemaLocation" => "http://yoururl.xsd",
   "error" => "No journeys found",
   "errorText" => "There was no journey found...",
   "$" => ""
     )
);
header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . json_encode($error) . ')';
```

Comment: I get this error in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.vasttrafik.se/bin/rest.exe/v1/departureBoard?authKey=*****************&format=json&id=1&direction=2?callback=onSuccess. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://forverkliga.se' is therefore not allowed access.

(I removed the authKey)

Comment: That's happening because the code in this answer invokes a json request, not a jsonp request. `onSuccess` should be replaced with `??`, jquery will then fill it in with it's own callback function name. That will of course bring you back to square one because the service doesn't properly use the callback parameter.

Comment: In my  answer I have modified the code to properly send params in your getJSON.

Comment: @AlexShilman I updated the question: I'm requesting a remote resource. That wasn't clear earlier. Does that change anything? I got the same error when I tried just now: XMLHttpRequest cannot load ....

Comment: @David, jsonp is only used to get data from remote source. I have updated my answer. Try it that way. Also can you post your server side code. The one that does the output.

Comment: This code: `$.getJSON(myurl + '?callback=?', 'authKey=***'+'&format=json&id='+id+'&direction='+direction,  function(result) {
console.log(result.DepartureBoard.errorText);
});`  (with the authKey removed) results in this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Comment: Are you setting headers properly before you output your jsonp from the server? header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8'); before you echo.

Comment: It really wouldn't hurt.